# Function gets called even though it has variable no of parameters?

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments

```
A(int a,int c,int d=1);

A(int a ,int b,int d){
   ....
}

main(){
   A(1,2);
}
```

In the above C++ code function A() gets called eventhough  parameters numbers are not same.
What might be the reason

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also, is it C or C++? The two languages behave differently.

Comment: Maybe there is a overload somewhere?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: http://ideone.com/xu8dtr.

Comment: This looks like clean C to me...

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors, I get `error: too few arguments to function ‘void A(int, int, func)’`. So no, it doesn't get called, because the parameters are not the same.

Comment: it is c++ code  and not c code

Answer (score 2):

The result depends on which version of C you are using. Pre-c89 compilers may compile the code, but c89 compilers or later will treat the parameter mismatch as an error.

Note that even if the code should compile, any reference to `fun` inside `A` will result in undefined behaviour.

Functions in C are only identified by their name, so the parameter list is not relevant in identifying a function. Hence, overloading is not possible in C. There can be only one function named `A` in a C program.